# Edit mode - Mirror on every axis

Tags: modeling, mirror

I am currently trying to model a [Companion Cube](https://i1.theportalwiki.net/img/6/6b/Portal2_CompanionCube.png) from Portal 2. I have started this by modelling the [corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNhag.png) of the cube. Now I want to mirror it on every axis to get 8 of these, just like the original cube has them. How do I achieve this? I want the final model to be fully 3d-printable, with no intersecting edges or modifiers when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to

- either set the cube's origin to the center of what the finished cube would be, or
- have an object there to use as a mirroring point.

Once you have done that, go to the modifiers tab to add a `Mirror Modifier`.

Set it to mirror along the X, Y & Z axis.

If you're using an object as the mirroring point, find a text bar labelled `Mirror Object` at the bottom of the Mirror modifier's options. You can then either

- type the object's name you wish to mirror with or
- select it with the eyedropper or
- select it out of the drop down box that should appear when you select the cube symbol on the left side of the text bar.

When you have got it mirrored, you should be ready to go onto prepping the model to 3D-Print. But to avoid intersecting edges, check the `clipping` option in the Mirror modifier's settings. Then select the entire edge on one of the mirroring planes and try to move it. If everything is lined up perfectly then the edges and vertices along mirror shouldn't be able to move along their relative axis.

Once you have done all this and are happy with the mirror's result, you can apply the modifier (Make sure `merging` is on first, even though it is one by default).

Then you can look into preparing it for 3D-Printing!
I hope you understood what I have written, good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use  the **Mirror Modifier with an Empty**.

1. Just align the Empty where you want to mirror your Object.
   Example:

[image]

---

2. Add a the **Mirror Modifier** to your *Cube* and use the Empty as the **Mirror Object**:

[image]
*Enable all Axis*

---

Now your Object is mirrored in every Axis:
[image]